GUI doesn't appear after starting Ubuntu 24.04 in dual boot with Windows 11 24h2
I started to use the dual boot on my Windows Home laptop some months ago. Everything worked fine until I updated my Windows 11 (in the meantime changed to education version by updating product key). I don't know if I messed by updating while grub was default in boot options and it caused Ubuntu to start in reboot instead of Windows, so I had to shutdown and restart by selecting Windows to finish. Everything seemed pretty good after the update, but at some point, while I was trying to understand why dislocker didn't show the Windows partition (encrypted with Bitlocker) correctly from Ubuntu, when I restarted the PC selecting Ubuntu the following errors appeared:

Then I tried to use the acpi=off options, but screen remains black. While with acpi=ht flag (only hyperthreading), I got the same messages. I use Ubuntu 24.04 and kernel 6.8.0-49-generic. BIOS is updated and I also tried when stuck in that page the Ctrl + Alt + F2 keyboard combination, logged in with my user account and tried to update the system to see of something changed, but it didn't.
I have no ideas anymore. I explained the update I did to Windows because I don't know if it is that that caused problems. In some forums it is said that Windows updates can mess up everything, but it seems crazy.
